# Triangle belongs to $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

> Show that the set $\{(x,y): 0\leq x,y \leq 1, x+y \leq 1\}$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

I know in general that any compact subset belongs to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. What could be the proof for, let's say, a triangle?

My thoughts is to use the definition the any rectangles form Borel $\sigma$-algebra by definition. This is, we can make a product of two intervals to get this set. Since $[0,1] = \cap_{n=1}^\infty(0-\frac{1}{n},1]$, $[0,1]$ belongs to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. What about the other dynamic interval that goes from 1 (at the point 0) to 0 (at the point 1)?

Comment: The set is closed and hence Borel. (I think one cannot help you, unless you let us know your exact definition of the Borel sigma-algebra you want to work with. A common definition is the sigma-algebra generated by the open sets and then it is clear that it contains all closed sets)

Comment: @user940347 I use definitions with semi-open intervals $(a,b]$. This is why I am looking for a proof of such intervals

Comment: Can you write down a precise definition of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ means a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The usual definition is that it is generated by open sets (and thus closed set). Then what is there to prove? Your set is closed.